# Django: adding a form from one app into another's app template (detail view)

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to add a form for the user to add a rating and a review comment, which updates a model from another app (rating app & items app).
I've been struggling with this for a while.
Right now I have:

**Ratings MODELS.py**

```
class Avaliacao(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    safra = models.ForeignKey(Safra,blank=False,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    nota = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES)
    comment = models.TextField()
```

**forms.py**

```
class NotaFormulario(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Avaliacao
        fields = ['nota','comment']
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^safra/(?P<safra_id>[0-9]+)/add_review/$',views.add_review, name='add_review')
]
```

**views.py**

```
def add_review(request, safra_id):
    safra = get_object_or_404(Safra, pk=safra_id)
    form = NotaFormulario(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        nota = form.cleaned_data['nota']
        comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
        usuario = request.user
        avaliacao = Avaliacao()
        avaliacao.safra = safra
        avaliacao.usuario = usuario
        avaliacao.nota = nota
        avaliacao.comment = comment
        avaliacao.created_at = datetime.datetime.now()
        avaliacao.save()

        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('vinhos:safra_detalhes', args=(safra.id,)))


    return render(request, 'vinhos/safra_detail.html', {'safra': safra, 'formulario': form})
```

**template.html (which is my detail template from another app)**

```
<form action="{% url 'notas:add_review' safra.id %}" method="post" >
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ formulario }}
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">


</form>
```

The `urls.py` path for the template (detail view page from another app) where the form is located is

```
path('safra/<int:pk>/',views.SafraDetalhes.as_view(), name='safra_detalhes'),
```

The fields are not rendering. The HTML look like this:

```
<form action="/safra/6/add_review/" method="post" >
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="ofbt2lvghvsNhPuSVRDtAgP3gYoGI55AIoXcA8EpUE29Sp">

  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">


</form>
```

The form only renders after I hit send once, then it renders with "This field is required" warning.

Overall I've been struggling with forms in Django, because on the apps I'm trying to develop there is always this cross-section of a form creating an instance on a model from one app on a detail view from another model from another app.

Comment: Just try to pass a form in GET method as well and check if it is seen.

Comment: It didn't work. I think it's about adding context to the detail view, but I'm stuck with a new range of errors when I try to use get_context_data on the detail view.